# Help with vehicle performance website

Tags: database

Creating a wordpress website for a family member i need to create a dropdown menu after something similar to this

[image]

Once the vehicle details are selected when clicking the view tuning options i need it to fetch data and return like this

[image]

What would be the best way to go about this? I understand i would require a database of the vehicles but am after the best way to go about this

Thanks

Comment: There must be some script out there already to do this. Depending on how much data you've got for the vehicle selection you can load one or two levels of select into the page, but after that you'll probably want to load the next level from the server and temporarily cache it in the browser too. So you'll need script to manage the selects, which you can hopefully find already written online, plus REST API endpoints to return data from the server, and some kind of storage for that in your database to read from.